# Android app not working on jelly bean device while minimum sdk version set to api level 15 android 4.0.3

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio . I have coded an app for record keeping. When I built it, I had set minimum android version to android 4.0.3. I have built this app completely. and also run on my own device running Android 6.0 It is also working fine on lollipop but not working on jelly bean and kitkat. Please help I have to use this app on jelly bean.
I am using Android Studio. All api level sdk are installed in Android sdk.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is it crashing? What line of code is causing the issue? Where are the crash logs? This is basic debugging, my friend. We aren't wizards who can look inside your code through a crystal ball.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I shared my application to the jelly bean phone via SHAREit from my lollipop phone. My application never opened. It always gave me an 'unfortunately stopped' message.

This time, I installed the application into the jelly bean through usb connect. Learn it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html). This may still cause your application to crash if your code is erroneous. But this method will help you find where your errors are. You can find statements about your errors or about the cause of failure in the logcat window of your android studio. Logcat window usually will open at the bottom of the ide once you run your application onto your phone.